# Saving and restoring different subset of settings while using cocoa bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings

I have an app where the user should be able to create template settings files, to save and choose from a popup list. These settings will be applied to configure an export of an item.

I just don't know how to best approach the problem of saving and restoring the saved settings.

To add to my problem is the fact that there are many different exporting methods, each with different setting types.

To explain:

User configures the settings they want for export method A, he/she saves these settings and here i want to write them to disk in a plist file.

The the user configures another set of settings for export method B, he/she saves these settings and i want to write these to disk aswell.

I have used NSSharedUsersDefaultsController to bind all interface elements and test bindings, but i don't want to keep all settings in the application plist. Also, I don't know if there is a good way of importing/exporting using that technique when i'm using different subset of settings. If there was a good way of binding to sub-dictionaries then that could work, but I have not been able to make that work.

I could create a Class for each export method and bind the settings to an NSObjectController, and then manually create an import and export method but that felt clunky.

NSDictionaryController and NSArrayController only seem to be made for TableViews and that kind of data display, not single user interface elements, at least from what i've been able to test.

So, is there a good way to create an export/import functionality while still using cocoa bindings, or do i have to create my own methods for that?

Any examples or pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered just persisting the values in the view that matters, and querying the view each time you export?  I am imagining these values matter on only one export Panel, and you just want that panel to save the user's last values...  using controllers and other persistence not baked into the Nib could be more than you need.

Comment: I think you are absolutely correct. I'm fairly new to programming in Cocoa and am always looking for a "correct" way of doing things, and in this case I have been overthinking it a bit. The obvious way is to just read and save each setting in a dict and control everything in the nib and it's controlling class. Thank you for helping me see that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and suggest way of saving not critical / not secure settings is:

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
```

You can access it like a dictionary with getObject: and setObject: